# PECL OAuth library for PHP - Works in browser, cant compile manually

Tags: php, oauth, pecl

I am using the PECL OAuth library for PHP which I installed correctly (well, I'm doubting that now). I use it for authentication before querying the LinkedIn API. 
In my code I create an OAuth object as in the example [here](https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/quick-start-guide#toggleview%3aid=php), see bottom. It gets the tokens, authorizes the user after he logged in, and successfully fetches data. But the funny thing is that it only works when I run the .php file through my browser (hosted in apache).

When I try to compile the code from the commandline the compiler says:
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'OAuth' not found in xxx.php on line 15

Obviously I already edited the php.ini to contain the following (or it would not work on the webpage):
extension=/usr/lib/php5/20090626/oauth.so

But when I type 'php -m' in the commandline I dont see the oauth module in the list. I have tried getting the filename/location by inserting these lines after making an instance of the OAuth object

```
$oauthc = new OAuth($oauth['linkedin']['consumerkey'], $oauth['linkedin']['consumersecret'],OAUTH_SIG_METHOD_HMACSHA1,OAUTH_AUTH_TYPE_URI);
$reflector = new ReflectionClass("OAuth");
$fn = $reflector->getFileName();
echo "[".dirname($fn)."]";
```

But this only returned the 2 brackets. I have no clue why it apparently works in the browser. Hopefully somebody can help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP can use different `php.ini` config files depending on what SAPI is currently in use. For example, there can be files (depends on linux distribution):

- `/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/*.ini` -> loaded when run in CLI mode
- `/etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/*.ini` -> loaded when run as an Apache module

So, probably your module is getting loaded when PHP runs as an Apache module, and not loaded for CLI

Comment: The ini was located at /etc/php5/cli/php.ini, but indeed, that did the trick. I even remember looking in that folder.. If I had googled 'php5 cli', the first hit "PHP: Command line usage" would have got me thinking... Anyway, thanks!